# ¿Cuál es el error en mi código?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algoritmos

Se trata de implementar el método de ordenamiento *Radix Sort* y que éste haga a su vez uso de *Counting Sort*. Me marca *"list index out of range"* cuando en la lista hay elementos de tamaño mixto, por ejemplo:

```
A = ['000','151','717','181','758','594','111','2','55']
```

Pero cuando son de las mismas dimensiones, por ejemplo:

```
A = ['000','151','717','181','758','594','111','222','552']
```

En este caso el programa corre sin problemas.

Éste es el código:

```
def SeparaCadena(cad):
    A2=[]
    for j in cad:
        A2.append(j)
    return A2

def CreaLista2(k):
    L=[]
    for i in range(k+1):
        L.append([0]*2)
    return L

def CreaLista(k):
    L=[]
    for i in range(k+1):
        L.append(0)
    return L

def obtenerElemSinClaves(E):
    Elem=[]
    Elem.append("000")
    for i in range(1, len(E)):
        Elem.append(E[i][0])
    return Elem

def FormaArregloConClaves(B,numCar):
    Btmp = []
    for i in range (len(B)):
        Btmp.append([B[i]]*2)
        A3=SeparaCadena(B[i])
        Btmp[i][1]=ord(A3[numCar-1])
    return Btmp

def CountingSort2(A,k):
    C=CreaLista(k)
    B=CreaLista2(len(A)-1)
    for j in range(1,len(A)):
        C[A[j][1]]=C[A[j][1]]+1
    for i in range(1,k+1):
        C[i]=C[i]+C[i-1]
    for j in range(len(A)-1, 0, -1):
        B[ C[A[j][1]] ] [1]=A[j][1]
        B[ C[A[j][1]] ] [0]=A[j][0]
        C[A[j][1]]=C[A[j][1]]-1
    return B

def radixSort(A):
    numCar=len(A[2])
    for i in range (numCar, 0, -1):
        cc= FormaArregloConClaves(A,i)
        print(cc)
        print()
        ordenado=CountingSort2(cc,15523)
        A=obtenerElemSinClaves(ordenado)
    return A

A = ['000','151','717','18','758','4','11','222','52']
print(radixSort(A))
```

Y los errores que marca son los siguientes:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-158-e77b46326794> in <module>()
      1 A = ['000','151','717','18','758','4','11','222','52']
----> 2 print(radixSort(A))

<ipython-input-157-7b41a9c4c33d> in radixSort(A)
     40     numCar=len(A[2])
     41     for i in range (numCar, 0, -1):
---> 42         cc= FormaArregloConClaves(A,i)
     43         print(cc)
     44         print()

<ipython-input-32-c4919abedfad> in FormaArregloConClaves(B, numCar)
     18         Btmp.append([B[i]]*2)
     19         A3=SeparaCadena(B[i])
---> 20         Btmp[i][1]=ord(A3[numCar-1])
     21     return Btmp
     22 

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Alguien me pueda decir mis errores si no es mucha molestia por favor.

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir el código de la función `FormaArregloConClaves()`?

Comment: Se me olvido, ya lo agrego.

Answer (score 3):

El problema inmediato está en el que `FormaArregloConClaves()` asume que todos los elementos serán del mismo largo. Entonces al llegar al cuarto elemento de la lista ('18'), `SeparaCadena()` retorna un arreglo de 2 elementos en lugar de uno de 3.

Esto se debe a que en `radixSort()` se está asumiendo de forma aparantemente arbitraria que el número de caracteres es el número de caracteres del tercer elemento de la lista '717'.

```
numCar=len(A[2])
```

Si el tercer elemento tuviera solo dos caracteres (como '18' o '4' en los ejemplos provistos), los errores serían bastantes distintos. En lugar de escoger un elemento arbitrario para seleccionar el tamaño, se podría encontrar el máximo número de caracteres:

```
longitudes=[]
for i in arreglo:
    longitudes.append(len(i))
long_max = max(longitudes)
```

o puede hacerse usando comprensión de listas:

```
long_max = max([len(x) for x in arreglo])
```

Los elementos más cortos deberán rellenarse para que tengan la misma longitud. Las cadenas de Python tienen una función `.zfill()` que agrega ceros a la izquierda:

```
>>> item = '2'
>>> item = item.zfill(3)
>>> print(item)
'002'
```

Antes de realizar comparaciones, es necesario homogenizar las longitudes para que haya elementos para comparar cuando se comparan las centenas, las decenas y las unidades en todos los casos.

Comment: Wow, gracias por tu valioso tiempo y consejos de verdad esto es de gran ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

El error en este código es que está utilizando una cantidad de caracteres fija (15523) para hacer el ordenamiento. Este valor se usa en la función CountingSort2 para crear una lista (C) con el tamaño adecuado. Sin embargo, esta cantidad puede variar dependiendo de los datos que se estén procesando. Esto puede provocar un IndexError si los caracteres tienen un valor más alto que 15523.

Una solución sería calcular el valor máximo de los caracteres y usar ese valor en lugar de 15523. De esta manera, se garantiza que la lista tenga suficientes posiciones para almacenar todos los valores de los caracteres.

```
def SeparaCadena(cad):
    A2=[]
    for j in cad:
        A2.append(j)
    return A2

def CreaLista2(k):
    L=[]
    for i in range(k+1):
        L.append([0]*2)
    return L

def CreaLista(k):
    L=[]
    for i in range(k+1):
        L.append(0)
    return L

def obtenerElemSinClaves(E):
    Elem=[]
    Elem.append("000")
    for i in range(1, len(E)):
        Elem.append(E[i][0])
    return Elem

def FormaArregloConClaves(B,numCar):
    Btmp = []
    for i in range (len(B)):
        Btmp.append([B[i]]*2)
        A3=SeparaCadena(B[i])
        Btmp[i][1]=ord(A3[numCar-1])
    return Btmp

def CountingSort2(A,k):
    C=CreaLista(k)
    B=CreaLista2(len(A)-1)
    for j in range(1,len(A)):
        C[A[j][1]]=C[A[j][1]]+1
    for i in range(1,k+1):
        C[i]=C[i]+C[i-1]
    for j in range(len(A)-1, 0, -1):
        B[ C[A[j][1]] ] [1]=A[j][1]
        B[ C[A[j][1]] ] [0]=A[j][0]
        C[A[j][1]]=C[A[j][1]]-1
    return B

def radixSort(A):
    max_val = 0
    numCar=len(A[2])
    for i in range(len(A)):
        for j in range(numCar):
            if ord(A[i][j]) > max_val:
                max_val = ord(A[i][j])
    for i in range (numCar, 0, -1):
        cc= FormaArregloConClaves(A,i)
        ordenado=CountingSort2(cc,max_val)
        A=obtenerElemSinClaves(ordenado)
    return A

A = ['000','151','717','18','758','4','11','222','52']
print(radixSort(A))
```